# House belongsTo Owner?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Wondering if "belongsTo" is write way to represent an ownership relationship where there is always a parent object, but the parent may switch.

ie if owner domain is

```
class Owner {
  String name

}
```

Should House be:

```
class House {
   String address
   Owner owner
}
```

or

```
class House {
   String address
   static belongsTo = [owner: Owner]
}
```

What I want to achieve is bi-direction 1:1 where I can either access owner.house or house.owner  and ability to change the owner without without deleting the old owner.

Answer (score 0):

`without deleting the old owner.` ?

So you have two choices - by far the easiest and where your current method is actually wrong should be  `Should House be:` maybe this?

```
class House {
   String address
   static hasMany = [owner:Owner]
   Owner currentOwner
}
```

With the relationships as it is, you are saying a house has many owner's. So owner1 owner2 ..  and it also has a current Owner which is Owner itself.
Each time you add a new entry you add it to the owner collection so `house.addToOwner(owner)` and you then set the last/latest update of `currentOwner=owner`.

Comment: Well, I guess it would be more accurate to say that a house has 1 current owner.  It may have had different owners in the past, but I don't really need to store that history in the object.

Comment: `It may have had different owners in the past, but I don't really need to store that history in the object` vs `owner and ability to change the owner without without deleting the old owner`  You could create a table that contains House and Owner and in that you register both Id's as a history - you can then look up and findAllByUser or House and be reconneted back to House or User object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate throw both entities, and the relation is 1:1 you can use `hasOne`

```
class Owner {
  String name
  static hasOne = [house: House]
}

class House {
   String address
   static belongsTo = [owner: Owner]
}
```